# Difference between _toHtml() and getGroupedHtml() in templates

Tags: theme, template, messages

Newer versions of Magento are using `_toHtml()` instead `getGroupedHtml()` in the template files.

But `Mage_Core_Block_Messages::_toHtml()` always just returns `$this->getGroupedHtml()` - Also back in Magento CE 1.5.1

Can anyone point out why it got changed in newer versions? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `_toHtml()` method:

Every block that extends `Mage_Core_Block_Template` can override that method to produce html output. The explanation is in `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` class (which is extended by the `Mage_Core_Block_Template` class).

```
final public function toHtml()
    {.....
        if ($html === false) {
            ....    
            $this->_beforeToHtml();
            $html = $this->_toHtml();
            $this->_saveCache($html);
            ....
         }
        $html = $this->_afterToHtml($html);
        ......
        return $html;
    }
```

and

```
protected function _toHtml()
    {
        return '';
    }
```

As you can see, `toHtml()` is a `final` method and you can't override it. Instead you can override `_toHtml()` and your html will be added to output by the `$this->_toHtml()` call.

2. `getGroupedHtml()` method:

It is defined in `Mage_Core_Block_Messages` and it provides messages in HTML format grouped by type.

```
public function getGroupedHtml()
    {
        $types = array(
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::ERROR,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::WARNING,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::NOTICE,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::SUCCESS
        );
        $html = '';
        ..........
        return $html;
    }
```

As you pointed out, the `Mage_Core_Block_Messages::_toHtml()` method calls the `getGroupedHtml()` to render the messages html output.

To wrap up, the methods `_toHtml()` and `getGroupedHtml()` are intended to serve different purposes.